# Can you help me to solve the recurrence relation $T(n) = T(\sqrt n) + 1 $?

Tags: algorithms

I have this recurrence relation to solve :

$T(n) = T(\sqrt n) + 1 $

I have tried to expand the recursion but I stopped here:

\begin{align}
T(n) &= T(n^{\frac12})+1\\
     &= T(n^{\frac14})+1+1\\
     &\text{after $i$ replacements I have}\\
     &= T(n^{\frac1{2^i}}) + i\\
\end{align}
I know that $T(1) = 1$

And now? How can I get to the solution?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. $1 = T(1) = T(\sqrt{1}) + 1 = T(1)+1 = 2$.

Comment: Note that if you hold the relationship for $n=1$, then you will have $T(1)=T(1)+1$ which is not possible for the reals.

Comment: Forgetting about the boundary condition which doesn't work, rewrite the recurrence relation as $T(k^2) = T(k) + 1$ (that is, take $n = k^2$).

Comment: Is it just $T(\sqrt{n})$ or rather one of $T(\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil)$, $T(\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor)$?

Comment: ... and you should look out for a solution where the resulting function has singularities at $n=1$ and $n=0$...

Comment: @Adam it's just T(sqrt(n))

Comment: @user1868607 then it doesn't make sense. $T(1)$ is unrelated to other values, because the only number $n$ such that $\sqrt{n}=1$ is $n=1$. What is the domain of $T$ and where did you find this relation? If it's relation for complexity of some algorithm, then i'm almost sure you want it to be ceiling or floor of $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @Adam Actually is an exercise for my Algorithm exam, It just says to resolve this recurrence relation...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's related to the algorithm complexity, then in this context $\sqrt{n}$ is likely to mean $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ (or $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$). So assume that $T(1) = 1$ and
$T(n) = T(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)+1$ for $n>1$.
Consider $n=2^{2^k}$:
$$\begin{align}
T\left(2^{2^k}\right)
&= T\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{2^{2^k}}\right\rfloor\right)+1 \\
&= T\left(2^{2^{k-1}}\right) + 1 \\
&= T\left(2^{2^{k-2}}\right) + 2 \\
&= \dots \\
&=T\left(2^{2^0}\right) + k \\
& = T(2) + k \\
&= T(1) + k + 1 \\
&= k+2
\end{align}$$
Now notice that:

1. $T\left(2^{2^{k+1}}-1\right)=T\left(2^{2^k}\right)$ (to see it just expand left hand side as above),
2. $T(n)\leq T(m)$ for $n\leq m$ (can be proven by induction).

From this we can conclude that $T(n)=\lfloor\log_2{(\log_2{n})}\rfloor+2$ for $n>1$.

Comment: can you please explain $T(2^{2^{k+1}}-1)=T(2^{2^k})$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n= 2^m$. Then
$$
\sqrt{n} = 2^{m/2} \quad\text{and}\quad m = \log n.
$$
Replacing $n=2^m$ in $T(n)$ gives
$$
T(2^m)= T(2^{m/2}) + 1.
$$
Now take
$$
s(m)= T(2^m).
$$
Therefore,
$$
s(m)= s(m/2) + 1.
$$
Now, applying Master rule :
$$
n^{\log_21} = n^0 = 1
$$
equals to $f(n)=1.$ Therefore,
$$
T(n)=s(m)= 1,
$$
and
$$
\log m = \log(\log n).
$$